# View older file version under mercurial with a different text editor without setting it as default

Tags: mercurial, sublimetext2, tortoisehg

I want to view an older version of my file under mercurial version control in Sublime Text (without setting it as the default editor via `ui.editor` option in `hrgc`)

Can I specify a different text editor from this command line?

```
hg cat -r 101 mycode.py
```

**Edit**:

FWIW, TortoiseHg lets you specify an editor by adding this to your `.hrgc`. I wish it was possible to do the same with command line.

```
[tortoisehg]
editor ="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe"
```

Comment: You can specify an editor on the command line with `--config ui.editor="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe` , but `hg cat` doesn't use the editor -- it is for sending files to standard output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg cat` just dumps the file to stdout and sublime text reads files from disk, so you'll need to send the file somewhere temporarily.

You could write a bash alias to do it in a blink, but it's nothing mercurial will do out of the box.  If you check the various Mercurial plugins for sublime you should be able to find something that opens files as specific versions for you.